# System.Linq.Dynamic Support for ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, linq, dynamic

I cannot get the latest install of System.Linq.Dynamic to work with ASP.NET 5. DNX core 5 is barking at it like "Querable" is not defined also System.Linq.Dynamic is not defined under the namespace System.Linq.

I downloaded the actual file from nuget, try doing the package manager in VS 2015, and still getting these errors.

Have anyone successfully got this library to work in VS 2015 ASP.NET 5?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

It appears as though I do not really need DNX Core 5.0 at this time so I simply removed it from the project.json, and things are fine. Once DNX Core 5.0 matures, I'll get back to it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Updated NuGet version which support **dnxcore50** can be found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/).

For more details see this github [project](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core).